# Where to override images rendering

Tags: media

I created my custom content type and add field called 'Image' of type Image and set the content manager can set multiple images into it. Now this field is rendered as such html

```html
<div class="field field-name-field-image field-type-image field-label-above">
  <div class="field-label">Image:&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">
      <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://mydomain.com/sites/default/files/img1.jpg" width="400" height="314" />
    </div>
    <div class="field-item odd">
      <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://mydomain.com/sites/default/files/img2.jpg" width="400" height="260" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I cannot find where are the template(s) which render this piece of html. I'd like to override it to render list of links, similar to

```html
<div class="field field-name-field-image field-type-image field-label-above">
  <div class="field-label">Image:&nbsp;</div>
  <ul class="field-items">
    <li><a href="http://mydomain.com/sites/default/files/img1.jpg">img1.jpg</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://mydomain.com/sites/default/files/img1.jpg">img2.jpg</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You probably dont want to do that, why dont you use 'https://drupal.org/project/linkimagefield' this instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is [`theme_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/theme_field/7) which could be customized by having the right *override* of the [`field.tpl.php`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7) template in your theme (through template suggestion, see the `theme_field()` function documentation.

Inside this function/template, the image is rendered by a field formatter. The `print render($item)` statement print that rendering. The exact used function/template depends on the configured formatter. If your are usign the default formatter, that would be [`theme_image_formatter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.field.inc/function/theme_image_formatter/7).

Note: See the [`theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7) function's documentation for how to override the `theme_*` functions in your theme or module.